# setbuf() - printf(), and write()

Tags: c, stream, buffer, file-descriptor

this is my first step on Stackoverflow !

So, I'm trying to use `setbuf()` to redirect `stdout` into a `char buffer[BUFSIZ]`. It works perfectly when I use `printf()`, but not at all when I use the system call `write()`.

Here is an example of code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int     main(void)
{
    char    buffer[BUFSIZ];

    freopen("/dev/null", "a", stdout);
    setbuf(stdout, buffer);
    printf("This works\n");
    write(stdout->_file, "This doesn't.\n", 14);
    fflush(stdout);
    freopen("/dev/tty", "a", stdout);
    printf("Buffer content :\n%s", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

> Buffer content :
>   This works

Do you have any idea why ?
Because for now I don't see how this work, I'll pipe stdout to stdin and then read the result - not the cleanest way of doing this I think.

Thank you, and have a nice day !

Comment: The `write` function completely bypasses the buffered standard I/O system.

Comment: As you said: `write` is not a standard C function. `setbuf` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`write`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) function is a low-level POSIX function that operates at a lower-level than the C standard output functions.

By using `write` directly you bypass the stdio buffering. If you want to use the buffer use the standard C [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) function instead.

Also note that `stdout` is a `FILE*`, and `FILE` is an opaque data structure. You should never attempt to use members of it directly.

Comment: You could mention POSIX `fileno()` that gets the file descriptor for a file stream cleanly.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the explanation ! I didn't know that setbuf() work with stdio buffer. I thought it was with file descriptor